# Change color of background on scroll down from right to left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help to achieve the same effect as in the following link: https://dumbo.design/team

when you scroll down the background becomes white and text changes the color. I need the same effect moving from right to left.

I don't know how to name this effect. I found how to change the color on scroll but I cant get the effect moving from right to left.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my question. I just made it! if anyone needs similar thing you can check the following link

```
jsfiddle.net/barlethamzai/ga5tk62f/
```